# IDA* and Admissibility of one Heuristic?

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, traversal, a-star, heuristics

I want to practice old exam on AI and see one challenging question and need help from some experts...

A is initial state and G is a goal state. Cost is show on edge and Heuristic "H" values is shown on each circle. IDA* limit is 7. 
We want to search this graph with IDA*. What is the order of visiting these nodes? (child is selected in alphabetical order and in equal condition the node is selected first that produce first.)

Solution is A,B,D,C,D,G.

[image]

> My question is how this calculated, and how we can say this Heuristic
>   is Admissible and Consistent?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how this calculated, and how we can say this Heuristic is Admissible and Consistent?

Let's first start with definitions of what are admissible and consistent heuristics:

1. An admissible heuristic **never overestimates the cost of reaching the goal**, i.e. the cost estimated to reach the goal is not greater than the cost of the shortest path from that node to the goal node in the graph.

   You can easily see that for all nodes `n` in the graph the estimation `h(n)` is always smaller or equal than the real shortest path. For example, h(B) = 0 <= 6 (B->F->G).
2. Let c(n, m) denote the **cost of an optimal path** in the graph from a node `n`
   to another node `n'`. A heuristic estimate function `h(n)` is consistent when
   `h(n) + c(n, m) <= h(n')` for all nodes `n , n'` in the graph. Another way of seeing the property of consistency is monotonicity. Consistent heuristic functions are also called monotone functions, due to the estimated final cost of a partial solution, is monotonically non-decreasing along the best path to the goal. Thus, we can notice that your heuristic function is not consistent.

   h(A) + c(A, B) <= h(B) -> 6 + 2 <= 0.

Let me do an analogy to explain it in a less mathematical way.
You are going for a run with your friend. At certain points you are asking your friend for how long does it take to finish your run. He is a very optimistic guy and he is always giving you a smaller time that you will be able to do, even if you run at your top all the rest of the way.
However, he is not very consistent in his estimations. At a point A he told you it will be **at least an hour more to run**, and after 30 minutes running you ask him again. Now, he is telling you that it is **at least 5 minutes more** from there. The estimation **in point A is less informative than in point B**, and therefore your heuristic friend is inconsistent.

Regarding the execution of IDA*, I copy-paste the *pseudocode* of the algorithm (I haven't tested) from the wikipedia:

```
 node              current node
 g                 the cost to reach current node
 f                 estimated cost of the cheapest path (root..node..goal)
 h(node)           estimated cost of the cheapest path (node..goal)
 cost(node, succ)  step cost function
 is_goal(node)     goal test
 successors(node)  node expanding function
 
 procedure ida_star(root)
   bound := h(root)
   loop
     t := search(root, 0, bound)
     if t = FOUND then return bound
     if t = ∞ then return NOT_FOUND
     bound := t
   end loop
 end procedure
 
 function search(node, g, bound)
   f := g + h(node)
   if f > bound then return f
   if is_goal(node) then return FOUND
   min := ∞
   for succ in successors(node) do
     t := search(succ, g + cost(node, succ), bound)
     if t = FOUND then return FOUND
     if t < min then min := t
   end for
   return min
 end function
```

follow the execution for your example is straightforward. First we set the bound (or threshold) with the value of the heuristic function for the start node. We explore the graph with a depth first search approach ruling out the branches which f-value is greater than the bound. For example, f(F) = g(F) + h(F) = 4 + 4 > bound = 6.
The nodes are explored in the following order: A,B,D,C,D,G. In a first iteration of the algorithm nodes A,B,D are explored and we run out of options smaller than the bound.

The bound is updated and in the second iteration the nodes C,D and G are explored. Once we reach the solution node with a estimation (7) less than the bound (8), we have the optimal shortest path.

Comment: What about Solution of A,B,D,C,D,G? would you please describe it?

Comment: my question has two parts, you answer just one part.